# Как выводить из массива элементы с тегами без указанного class

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив, в котором хранятся элементы вместе с тегами. У некоторых тег пустой, а у некоторых указан определенный, одинаковый `class`. Как вывести все элементы, которые не имеют параметра `class`, а остальные не выводить?

```php
Array(
      [0] => "<div>Тест0</div>",
      [1] => "<div class="custom">Тест1</div>",
      [2] => "<div class="custom">Тест2</div>"
      )
```

Comment: отфильтровать к примеру array_filter()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Организовать поиск внутри массива с помощью array_filter()

```
$a = [
    '<div>Тест0</div>',
    '<div class="custom">Тест1</div>',
    '<div class="custom">Тест2</div>'
];

$arr = array_filter($a, function($i) {
    return !preg_match('~<div class="custom">~', $i);
});

echo '<pre>'; var_dump($arr); echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: А если вместо `'<div>Тест0</div>',` будет `'<div>Текст, содержащий "class"</div>',` ?

Comment: @P. Fateev если автор подтвердит ваше предположение, я перепишу пример с использованием регулярного выражения.

Comment: @P. Fateev подправил код.